# IIS permission/authentication issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

Recently I reset the IIS service and my project stop working properly.

I kept two authentication: anonymous Authentication and Windows authentication.

When I disable windows, project get error for access database. (anonymous user can not access)
When I disable anonymous,project keeps my windows name as the login name.
when I enableboth, the login in is ok but the userID is null for all the pages.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace Worldsmart.Smart.Cardholder.Portal.Models
{
   public class ClaimModel
   {
      public static Guid GetUserID(HttpContextBase context)
      {
         Guid userID;

         try
         {
            userID = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
            userID = new Guid();
         }

         return userID;
      }
   }
}
```

is there anyone can help me about this? Because When I transfer the project to another machine it works, therefore, the problem seems not to be the project itself.

Cheers

Comment: Exactly what do you consider to be 'works'? Are you supposed to be using client's Windows logins for access to the database, or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if I'm on track but all interactions with the database should be done through windows authentication, make sure that the un and pw in the web.config match to one of the users on the database

Comment: The behavior Eric describes suggests that he is using integrated authentication. It's difficult to tell if that's what he *wants*, though.